# httr POST authentication error

Tags: r, api, post, httr

I am trying to structure a POST json request using httr. The API documentation proposes the following the CURL request:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization:Token XXXXXXXXX" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{\"texts\":[\"A simple string\"]}" https://api.uclassify.com/v1/uclassify/topics/classify
```

My R httr implementation is the following:

```
POST("https://api.uclassify.com/v1/uClassify/Topics/classify", 
    encode="json",
    add_headers('Authorization:Token'="XXXXXXXXX"),
    body=("A simple string"))
```

But I received a 401 error message which indicates that my authentication failed. Any suggestion on how I can implement the CURL request on httr?

Answer (score 4):

Just in case it can help somebody else, the below code works for me:
    `POST("https://api.uclassify.com/v1/uClassify/Topics/classify", 
          encode="json",
          add_headers(Authorization = "Token XXXXXXXXX"),
          body = "{\"texts\":[\"A simple string\"]}")`